# DOtNetDuke Module having Missing Refrences Error (Christoc Module)

Tags: c#, module, dotnetnuke

i don't know whats wrong with my DNN modules now, i ceate new DAL2 project and save it build it and it works fine even on the template, but when i close my VS code after saving everything properly when i reopen the project it starts giving me errors for missing references even thought i added them when i was creating.

i added few references which i added manually, which i added while creating module but its not even picking the references which were added by the system by itself, now i just created a new project and am afraid to close it, can anyone tell me whats wrong here, is there anything am doing wrong, cause this is my daily routine work never happened just started from yesterday

Given below is the snapshot of application after closing and then opening
[image]

Kindly review and give feedback.

Answer (score 0):

1) Did you carefully follow my instructions for where to place the module? Is the path of the project file /desktopmodules/MODULENAME/modulename.csproj? Or perhaps it is two levels down, /modulename/modulename/modulename.csproj?

2) Did you open Visual Studio as an Administrator?

3) Check in IIS to see if there is a virtual directory/application configured on the desktopmodules folder, or perhaps on your module's folder, if so, right click and remove.